# PHPMyadmin #1066 - Not unique table/alias error only export

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, export

I'm actually having an issue with PHPMyAdmin :

- I can execute my SQL query with nice result
- I get an error when I'm trying to export the same query

Here's the query :

```
SELECT pn.nomenclature_id as nomenclature_id, pn.lettre as lettre, a.reference as reference_article, at.nom as nom_article
FROM item a, item_translation at, item_nomenclature an, item_nomenclature pn, item p 
WHERE a.type = 1
AND a.id = at.id
AND at.lang = 'fr'
AND a.id = an.item_id
AND an.nomenclature_id = pn.nomenclature_id
AND pn.item_id = p.id
AND p.type = 2
AND p.marque_id = 2
```

Here's a video where I had the problem : https://youtu.be/Z5AAZhoX6W0

There's lot of thread on Not unique table/alias error but I didn't found any reason to explain why the query works in PHPMyAdmin "SQL" tab but not with export.

Thanks for your support,
David.

Comment: PhpMyAdmin sometimes modifies queries when, like when it adds `LIMIT` to show the first 25 rows of the output. It sounds like whatever it does to the query to do Export causes a duplicate table name.

Comment: @Barmar si there's no solution ? Does it justify a phpmyadmin issue support ticket on the dev project ?

Comment: That's what I would do.

Comment: It's done : https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13187

Answer (score 1):

For anyone running into this same issue and not able to apply the fix mentioned in the github issue for whatever reason (I'm working on a VPS currently where I have no access to the phpMyAdmin install).

A simple workaround is to first create a view from your query result, then go to that view and export from there. Afterwards you can drop the view again.

(to create the view just run your query but click 'create view' instead of export, fill in a name and leave the rest as is; the view will become available in the left column under the node 'Views' instead of 'Tables')